# Mockito: creating a parameter matcher for a class

Tags: mockito, junit4

Given a method definition as follows:

```
MyClass.myMethod(SecondClass secondClass);
```

and a mock of MyClass:

```
MyClass myClass = mock(MyClass.class);
```

how would you match the method parameter when defining the expecation?

```
when(myClass.myMethod(???)).thenReturn(null);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
when(myClass.myMethod(Mockito.any(SecondClass.class))).thenReturn(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Mockito.any(SecondClass.class)
```

or

```
(SecondClass)any()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best way to do it is

```
doReturn(object).when(myClass).myMethod(???);
```

in `???` you have some possibilities.

- You can pass a given object and then you wait for an especific one
- Or you can pass `Mockito.any(Clazz.class)` and then you will accept any object of that kind